# Manjaro On Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen

After the last update of Manjaro the screen now just boots to a flashing cursor.  I had Plasma KDE appearing prior to the update.  Everything still runs as I can ssh into the PI but the screen previously went into sleep mode after booting & I could get into gui via tiger-vnc.  Now I just get the cursor and the screen stays illuminated but blank.